# looped values are not printing in div via javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to print the address and details  of my clinics in various locations. However, when i try to do that it is only printing the first element in my div.

Here is my code

```
    var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
               var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
               for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
                 var id = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("id");
                 var locname = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("locationName");
                 var locaddress = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("locationAddress1");
                 var address = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("locationAddress1");
                 var distance = parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("distance"));
                 var servicename = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("serviceName");
                 var clinicfname= markerNodes[i].getAttribute("clinicFname");
                 var cliniclname= markerNodes[i].getAttribute("clinicLname");
                 var clinicname= clinicfname + ' ' + cliniclname ;
                 var clinicAddress= markerNodes[i].getAttribute("clinicAddress");
                 var clinicCity= markerNodes[i].getAttribute("clinicCity");
                 var clinicPhone= markerNodes[i].getAttribute("clinicPhone");
                 var cname= markerNodes[i].getAttribute("cname");
                 var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
                      parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("locationLat")),
                      parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("locationLong")));
                  document.getElementById('details_name').innerHTML = clinicname;


                      //console.log (parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("locationLong")));

                 createdetails(clinicname,clinicAddress)
                 bounds.extend(latlng);
               }
```

In above code am calling a function name `createdetails`

```java
    function createdetails(clinicname,clinicAddress)
    {
     document.getElementById("details_name").innerHTML=clinicname;
     document.getElementById("details_address").innerHTML=clinicAddress;
    }
```

But this div is priniting only first name and first addrees.It have 9 diffrent values for name and address.When i consoled it,it prints.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and make a [mcve] with example xml

Comment: you call 9 times the function which every time overrides the innerHTML of two elements. So only the last address will be innerHTML-ed

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling `document.getElementById("details_name").innerHTML = ...`, you are overwriting the current value. Maybe you should append the new name to the existing content with `+=`:

```js
function createdetails(clinicname,clinicAddress)
{
 document.getElementById("details_name").innerHTML+=clinicname;
 document.getElementById("details_address").innerHTML+=clinicAddress;
}
```

Comment: It doesnt works, it print only first clinic name,,multiple time